# android dialog style properties

Tags: android, colors, dialog

I want to change color of the blue parts in the following image: [image: dialog]

I know how to use custom styles, I just need to know what are called the properties of these blue parts (I mean something like `<item name="android:background">#FF0000</item>` ) thx

What I really want to achieve is demonstrated here:
[image: dialog2]

Comment: which blue parts are you talking about? what API are you using?

Comment: look at the image, Title, line under title, and lines above and under the selected values for day/month/year. min api7

Answer (score 0):

You may inherit the theme used from Android code and change particulars within that.

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/themes.html

```
<style name="GreenText" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance">
    <item name="android:textColor">#00FF00</item>
</style>
```

parent holds the value of the default theme. In your case it will be the Dialog theme for Holo.

Comment: I know, what I am asking here is what should be instead of `textColor` for these blue lines